# Center Brand in Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to center the brand in a bootstrap navbar and also have other menu items on the left and right.

I've got working code, as per [here](http://www.bootply.com/9toJrFqb7M), however the issue I have is the form field, namely the search box, isn't usable as the width of the brand is set to 100%.

http://www.bootply.com/9toJrFqb7M

Code reposted for convenience:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top top-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapse-content" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
          </form>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use left position to center your `navbar-brand`, instead of setting its width to 100%

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/lkW4qVO0KP)

Comment: hmm. it doesn't seem to centre it though, it seems offset to the right. comparing my bootply with yours there is a notable difference.

Comment: @m0atz Well the offset is upto you, yeah see 50% is a little too towards left. but you can always customize it according to your need. 45% looks good though